# EF Core: can I put a subquery returning a single result to a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

If in EF Core in C# I use something like this:

```cs
var result = myQuery.Where(x => x.someAttribute <= myQuery.Max(y => y.someAttribute)).ToList();
```

then EF Core executes just a single query.

Now I would like to store the result of `myQuery.Max(y => y.someAttribute)` into a variable, because the resulting query is extensive in my case.

But if I do something like this:

```cs
var myMax = myQuery.Max(y => y.someAttribute);
var result = myQuery.Where(x => x.someAttribute <= myMax).ToList();
```

Of course it results in the execution of two queries. The same applies for `Min` or `FirstOrDefault`. Can such a sub-query be stored into a variable without getting them evaluated immediately, so it finally runs just in a single query?

Comment: Not possible to achieve in LINQ, unless you are implementing the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Even in SQL this would require two queries, unless you use window functions. What exactly would you want to happen, if you wrote it in SQL what would it look like?

Comment: Assuming that you mean `== myMax` (otherwise, what's the point?), conceptually, it's just `myQuery.GroupBy(y => y.someAttribute).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).First()`. But, unfortunately, EF-core (up to v8) doesn't translate this. So, not an answer (yet).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to break your LINQ query into multiple parts because you want to make it more readable.
Keeping it in a variable like you've shown above would use up some memory, or pointer size.
Instead, using an `Expression` would be better.

Example:

```
 Expression<Func<List<myQuery>, int>> SomeAttributeIsMax = x => x.Max(x => x.someAttribute);
```

In the above sample code, I've created a class of type `myQuery` with an `int` property called `someAttribute`.

Comment: How to use that?

Comment: Looks promising, but how to use it? E.g. query.Where(x => x.SomeAttr == SomeAttributeMax???)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use a window function in this case, probably `MAX OVER` or `DENSE_RANK`, but I don't think EF Core can do `DENSE_RANK`.

You can get EF Core to generate window functions by selecting out of a `groupby`.

```cs
var result = await (
    from x in myQuery
    group x by 1 into g // use a constant to do `OVER ()`
    from x2 in g
    where x2.someAttribute <= g.Max(x3 => x3.someAttribute)  // did you mean = not <= ???
    select x2
).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I wanted to split a big query into smaller pieces, where one of the sub-query is Max in my case.

Comment: Then can you give a clearer example of what you actually want to do, as currently it just appears you want the top result.